# Increment a value inside of a Promise all

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, es6-promise

In my project I am trying to create a few `Invoices`, update `Packages` and send emails inside of a `Promise.all`.

I am using `nodejs`, `express` and `sequelize`.

For example this is part of my code:

```js
exports.createInvoices = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Other logic...

    const lastInvoice = await Invoice.findOne({
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
      attributes: ['number'],
    });

    let number = lastInvoice.number + 1;

    await Promise.all(_.map(pckByBox, async (pck) => {
      const user = await User.findOne(...);

      await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
        // This is the important part
        const invoice = await Invoice.create({
          userId: user.id,
          total: pck.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.totalPrice, 0),
          number,
          isAffiliate: !!(user.affiliateCardNo || user.affiliateDate),
          byId: by.id,
        }, { transaction: t });

        await Promise.all(pck.map(async (p) => {
          await Packages.update(some data);
        }));

        const invoiceData = await Invoice.findOne(some query);

        await sendEmail(email, data);
      });
    }));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

The functions create well the `Invoices`, update the `Packages` and send the emails. But if I create more than one invoice, it creates with the same number.

I tried to put:

```js
number++;
```

Inside of the sequelize transaction, after the transaction.

Also the `lastInvoice` function inside of the `Promise` like the `User.findOne`, also inside of the transaction and everytime the number doesn't increment.

How can I increment the number?

Comment: The only correct way to do this is to use an auto-incrementing field in your database. Don't do this in Node.

Comment: @Evert That was my first idea but I am migrating the database from firebase to postgresql, and the data in the column number is not continuous and sometimes it skip a number. I tried to create that column as auto-increment but when I run the migration I got an error.

Comment: What's the issue with using non-continuous numbers? It's somewhat normal to expect this with relational databases that there will be gaps. If you don't see a way to handle this on the database, the real reason this is happening is because you're using Promise.all which starts all your transactions in parallel. Use a regular loop and do things 1 at a time.

Comment: If you have an auto-increment column in PostgreSQL then you have a sequence for it and so you can set the starting number in it equal to the next number after the maximum one in the existing records